# Unable to pass NSString between ViewControllers, while other objects can

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have two view controllers, which one passes and array of objects to the other as expected. However when I try to pass a string, somehow something happens because on the other ViewController it always returns as (null). Any thing im missing here?

**ViewController one.h**

```
@class ViewControllerTwo;

@interface ViewControllerOne : UIViewController{

    ViewControllerTwo* playboard;

@property(nonatomic, retain) ViewControllerTwo* playBoard;

@end
```

**ViewController One**

```
playBoard = [[ViewControllerTwo alloc] init];    
        [playBoard setQuickPlayFilters:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];
        [playboard setChallenge:[[NSString alloc] init]];


passToPlayboard = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"one"];                    
                    filters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:5],
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:9],
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:8], nil];

  [playBoard setQuickPlayFilters:[filters mutableCopy]];
      [playboard setChallenge:[NSString stringWithString:passToPlayboard]];

Touch_TestingAppDelegate* appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
      [appDelegate.navController pushViewController:playBoard animated:YES];
```

**ViewController Two.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewControllerTwo : UIViewController {
    NSString* challenge;
NSMutableArray* quickPlayFilters;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString* challenge;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* quickPlayFilters;

@end
```

**ViewController Two.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    cover = [[CoverView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140.0f, 80.0f, 620.0f, 610.0f) andRemaningTiles:[quickPlayFilters lastObject]];
    cover.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview:cover];

    NSLog(@"Quick Play : %@", quickPlayFilters);
    NSLog(@"Challenge from Load : %@", challenge);


    [[self cover] setFilters:[quickPlayFilters mutableCopy]];

    timerDisplay = [[TimerDisplay alloc] 
                    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(813.f, 120.f, 181.f, 162.f) 
                    andTimeCycle:[quickPlayFilters objectAtIndex:0] 
                    andNumberOfRows:[quickPlayFilters objectAtIndex:6]]; 
}
```

And when i look for the `quickPlayFilters` in `playBoard` I can find them right away. However i can not return anything other than null for the `challenge` string. Please help.

Comment: Can we see the .h implementation for ViewControllerOne?

Comment: And your implementation of setChallenge:

Comment: @FelipeCypriano is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Indeed it is, and see @XJones's answer below; he sums it up rather nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is a typo in `ViewControllerTwo.h`. The `playboard` iVar is in all lowercase but the property is in camelcase (`playBoard`). This is causing your class to have two iVars (`playboard` and `playBoard`). Fix the typo so everything is `playBoard` and it will work.

My initial answer below is left for reference as I still recommend you clean up your code as I recommended. I revised the code to use `playBoard` in all instances.

= ORIGINAL ANSWER

This is impossible to answer for sure w/o seeing your code in `ViewControllerTwo.m`. Make sure the property for `challenge` is defined as:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy)  NSString * challenge;
```

If you have a custom setter, make sure it is doing the correct assignment ala:

```
- (void)setChallenge:(NSString *)newChallenge
{
    if (![challenge isEqualToString:newChallenge]) {
        challenge = [newChallenge copy];
        // whatever else you need to do
    }
}
```

You're creating a bunch of objects you don't really need. You're code above could be:

```
playBoard = [[ViewControllerOne alloc] init];    
passToPlayBoard = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"one"];
filters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:5],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:9],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:8], nil];

[playBoard setQuickPlayFilters:filters];
[playBoard setChallenge:passToPlayBoard];

Touch_TestingAppDelegate* appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.navController pushViewController:playBoard animated:YES];
```

NOTE: my code above assumes your project is using ARC. If not, you'll have to release the objects appropriately.

EDIT: found the actual problem. added to the top of this answer.

Comment: What is the difference between this two lines?

passToPlayboard = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"one"];

passToPlayboard = @"one";

Comment: Depending on if you're using ARC or not, the first one is allocating (and never releasing) an NSString.  This will cause a memory leak.  The second one is good for both as the system will handle releasing it.

Comment: that's true regarding what ARC does but that's not the difference. The compiler will optimize direct references to a string (e.g. `@"one") so they will all be the same object. Using `initWithString` causes a new object to be created. Generally this is a moot point and it's fine to use the string directly. You'll end up replacing all those if/when you get into localization.

Comment: I tried adjusting my code, no luck still. What has me the most confused is that `filters` is passed over with no problem, but challenge does'nt seem to want to go. Also i am not using a custom setter... should i be?

Comment: no, you don't need a custom setter. post `ViewControllerTwo.h` and the `init` and `viewDid...` methods from `ViewControllerTwo.m`.

Comment: Done, but no init method in viewControllerTwo.m

Comment: you have a typo. see my revised answer.

Comment: no worries, I can't tell you how many times I've had similar bugs. the trick is finding them before resorting to SO! :) happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

In the setChallenge method please retain your object value..like.

- (void)setChallenge:(NSString *)newChallenge
  {

  ```
  challenge = [newChallenge retain];
  ```

  }